# django output empty csv

Tags: python, django, csv

I'm using django and I'm trying to export the CSV_data list into csv file. Below is my csv.py:

```
#coding=utf-8
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import loader, Context
from demo.views import CSV_data


def output(request, filename):
    response = HttpResponse(mimetype='text/csv')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=%s.csv' % filename

    t = loader.get_template('csv.txt')
    c = Context({
        'data': CSV_data,
    })
    response.write(t.render(c))
    return response
```

CSV_data is a variable in views.py, I tried to print it in template, the value is ok.

```
 [(u'2012-06-01', [0, 0, 0]), ('2012-06-08', [0, 0, 0]), ('2012-06-15', [0, 0, 0]),    ('2012-06-22', [0, 0, 0]), ('2012-06-29', [0, 0, 0]), ('2012-07-06', [0, 0, 0]), ('2012-07-13', [0, 0, 0]), ('2012-07-20', [0, 0, 0]), ('2012-07-27', [0, 0, 0]), ('2012-08-03', [131, 164, 79.88]), ('2012-08-10', [110, 198, 55.56]), ('2012-08-17', [112, 197, 56.85]), ('2012-08-24', [147, 283, 51.94]), ('2012-08-31', [0, 306, 0.0]), ('2012-09-07', [418, 418, 100.0]), ('2012-09-14', [342, 342, 100.0]), ('2012-09-21', [732, 732, 100.0]), ('2012-09-28', [689, 689, 100.0]), ('2012-10-05', [775, 775, 100.0]), ('2012-10-12', [469, 469, 100.0]), ('2012-10-19', [477, 477, 100.0]), ('2012-10-26', [897, 897, 100.0]), ('2012-11-02', [216, 216, 100.0]), ('2012-11-09', [1046, 1046, 100.0]), ('2012-11-16', [840, 840, 100.0]), ('2012-11-23', [948, 948, 100.0])]
```

However, the generated csv is always empty.

I tried to add the CSV_data definition to the csv.py file, like this:

```
#coding=utf-8
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import loader, Context

CSV_data = [(u'2012-06-01', [0, 0, 0]), ('2012-06-08', [0, 0, 0]), ('2012-06-15', [0, 0, 0]), ('2012-06-22', [0, 0, 0]), ('2012-06-29', [0, 0, 0]), ('2012-07-06', [0, 0, 0]), ('2012-07-13', [0, 0, 0]), ('2012-07-20', [0, 0, 0]), ('2012-07-27', [0, 0, 0]), ('2012-08-03', [131, 164, 79.88]), ('2012-08-10', [110, 198, 55.56]), ('2012-08-17', [112, 197, 56.85]), ('2012-08-24', [147, 283, 51.94]), ('2012-08-31', [0, 306, 0.0]), ('2012-09-07', [418, 418, 100.0]), ('2012-09-14', [342, 342, 100.0]), ('2012-09-21', [732, 732, 100.0]), ('2012-09-28', [689, 689, 100.0]), ('2012-10-05', [775, 775, 100.0]), ('2012-10-12', [469, 469, 100.0]), ('2012-10-19', [477, 477, 100.0]), ('2012-10-26', [897, 897, 100.0]), ('2012-11-02', [216, 216, 100.0]), ('2012-11-09', [1046, 1046, 100.0]), ('2012-11-16', [840, 840, 100.0]), ('2012-11-23', [948, 948, 100.0])]

def output(request, filename):
    response = HttpResponse(mimetype='text/csv')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=%s.csv' % filename

    t = loader.get_template('csv.txt')
    c = Context({
        'data': CSV_data,
    })
    response.write(t.render(c))
    return response
```

Then the output csv is not empty. So I guess there's something wrong when import CSV_data from views.py.

The problem is I've tested that CSV_data value in views is correct. So what could go wrong?

***************************UPDATE*********************************:

original code in views.py is like:

```
 CSV_data = []
 def part_usage_result(request):
     ...(details omit)
     usageDictWeek = helper.getResultByWeek(modelName, spareCode, start, end) #returns a list
     CSV_data=usageDictWeek
```

I change to:

```
 CSV_data = []
 def part_usage_result(request):
     ...(details omit)
     usageDictWeek = helper.getResultByWeek(modelName, spareCode, start, end) #returns a list
     for each in usageDictWeek:
         CSV_data.append(each)
```

Now the content of csv is correct.
Still don't know why this happens

Comment: you have to go deeper :) what is relevant code for `helper.getResultByWeek`? how is `part_usage_result` invoked? does CSV_data[:] = usageDictWeek help?

Comment: Yes CSV_data[:] = usageDictWeek works! I guess I need to learn more Python :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you didn't provide `helper.getResultByWeek` details and how it is called, I guess it returns a global variable with a list value, and this variable is modified somewhere in between.

```
 CSV_data = usageDictWeek
```

do not copy a list, but creates another reference to existing one. When later original `usageDictWeek` is modified, CSV_data is modified as well.

When you do instead

```
 CSV_data[:] = usageDictWeek
```

a new copy of `usageDictWeek` is created and assigned to CSV_data.

Answer (score 0):

try keyword `content_type`, instead of mimetype

Comment: Still the same. I did some change in views.py and the csv is not empty now. Please see update in question